# jaxb set string type

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb

How can I get JAXB to marshall a string or primitive data type and set the type="string", or type="int" in the resulting XML.  I have tried specifying a specific type for each field

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "string",namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",type = String.class)
```

But this makes no difference the resulting XML is without type.

Thanks for reading

***Update***
this is basically what I have in a JaxB class:

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected Keys keys;
protected String workflowID;
    protected String fromFigure;
    protected String fromPort;
```

This is the resulting XML

```
        <keys type="draw2d.ArrayList">
            <data type="Array">
                <element type="draw2d.FlowConnectionModel">
                    <workflowID>d8f71b92-dc69-4115-9095-d748265d4e68</workflowID>
                    <fromFigure>706531d9-cd03-4347-9ba2-d9b525035e0d</fromFigure>
                    <fromPort>out_right_initialState</fromPort>
```

Notice that there is a type set for the keys, data and element types but none for the primitive data types of workflowID, fromFigure and fromPort.  What I want is this:

```
        <keys type="draw2d.ArrayList">
            <data type="Array">
                <element type="draw2d.FlowConnectionModel">
                    <workflowID type="string">d8f71b92-dc69-4115-9095-d748265d4e68</workflowID>
                    <fromFigure type="string">706531d9-cd03-4347-9ba2-d9b525035e0d</fromFigure>
                    <fromPort type="string">out_right_initialState</fromPort>
```

Comment: Types are specified in the XML schema definition(xsd). Please specify exactly what you're trying to do and why?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. within the applicaiton I am working on is a loose xml javascript parser which requires a type attribute to be specified for every element, including primitive types. The schema used to generate the jaxb classes (which can be done without schema also btw) specifies type as string and the generated classes are of type string but when marshalling the only types that are populated are those that are complex (arrays or other classes or lists) not the primitive types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to change the schema to use complex types as opposed to simple types.
A snippet from the original schema

```
     <xs:element name="layoutWorkflowID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="layoutInstanceID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

Changed to this

```
    <xs:element ref="layoutWorkflowID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element ref="layoutInstanceID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

With extra complex types

```
  <xs:element name="layoutWorkflowID">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:NCName">
      <xs:attribute name="type" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

And now I get what I need when marshalling with every type specified.

```
<layoutWorkflowID type="string">WorkflowHTML</layoutWorkflowID>
<layoutInstanceID type="string">6</layoutInstanceID>
```

Thanks for those that responded and read.

Answer (score 1):

You will not see any difference in produced XML. You are expected to see difference in XSD if you generate it from your class.